# C array initialization at end of struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm learning C and I am confused about this stuct I came across, but I think maybe it is short hand for simply creating a struct array.

```
struct myStruct
{
    char *name;
    int id;
} myList[] = {
  {"bob", 1},
  {"joe", 2}
};
```

Is the same as

```
struct myStruct
{
    char *name;
    int id;
};
struct myStruct myList[]  = {
  {"bob", 1},
  {"joe", 2}
};
```

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Isn't `("bob", 1)` identical to `1`? Otherwise, yes, it's equivalent. But don't forget the semicolon after the `struct` definition.

Comment: For me it doesn't compile on `gcc` with `-std=c11` flag. This doesn't seem to be standard C.

Comment: It's most likely `{"bob", 1}`, not `("bob", 1)`.

Comment: Yes sorry, typed this up with wrong brackets.

Comment: At first I thought this code won't compile because it is assigning const char*  to char* , but it did. I am confused now

Comment: @texasbruce; What is confusing here?

Comment: @texasbruce In C, string literals are `char*` not `const char*`.

Comment: @n.m.  I remember string literal should be bound to `const char*` only, but it works fine in both C and C++ to just assign to a variable `char*` which is very dangerous. I must be crazy or something.

Comment: @texasbruce, n.m. is right that C string literals represent arrays of `char`, not of `const char`, but the standard does specify that "If  the program attempts to modify such an array,  the behavior is undefined" (C2011 6.4.5/7).  Some compilers -- gcc for example -- can help you detect such undefined behavior at compile time by treating string literals as arrays of `const char`, contrary to the standard.  In gcc, this is enabled by `-Wwrite-strings`.

Comment: @texasbruce in C++ string literals are `const char*`, crank up your warning level.

Comment: @n.m. That makes more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the same. The first syntax is useful in situations when you would like to keep the type of your `struct` anonymous:

```
struct {
    char *name;
    int id;
} myList[] = {
    {"bob", 1},
    {"joe", 2}
};
```

Comment: Why would I want to do that?

Comment: @BarryBones41 Sometimes you just don't need a tag name for your struct - for example, when you never declare the same struct in any other place, and the `struct` itself is local to a file (i.e. `static`) or local to a function in which it is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They are same. It is similar to

```
int i = 1;
```

and

```
int i;
i = 1;
```